# Have your WebSite recognized as a Search Engine by Chrome

Tags: web-applications, seo, google-chrome, search-engine, opensearch

If I start typing stackov.. in Chrome I can see something like *'Press Tab to search
 stackoverflow.com'*.

SO is basically recognized as a Search Engine.
Do you have any idea of how to implement the same sort of [feature](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95653) in our WebApp?

I think it should be related with [OpenSearch](http://www.opensearch.org/Home)

```
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="http://sstatic.net/so/opensearch.xml">
```

thanks

**edit**:

I think it should be just a matter of specifing an xml defined in this way (http://sstatic.net/so/opensearch.xml)

```
    <OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"

                       xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/"> 
  <ShortName>Stack Overflow</ShortName> 
  <Description>Search stackoverflow.com for answers to your programming questions</Description> 
  <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding> 
  <Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico</Image> 
  <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://stackoverflow.com/search?q={searchTerms}"></Url> 
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

and this is the *URL* that will be used.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q={searchTerms}
```

*searchTerms* will be populated with the string you typed-in in chrome

Comment: As I read it, it doesn't say "search *with* stackoverflow", it says search the domain stackoverflow.com (using whatever search engine Chrome uses), as in "site:stackoverflow.com search terms".

Comment: I preferred this answer here about "How to let Google Chrome detect a site search engine?": https://stackoverflow.com/a/14082569/470749

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right track there. It's [OpenSearch](http://www.opensearch.org/Home) you're looking for. They have some [how-to guides](http://www.opensearch.org/Documentation/Developer_how_to_guide) and tutorials on how to implement this on your own website.