# How to let Google detect a site search engine?

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome has a feature where you can hit tab to search a site. Chrome then navigates to the site's own search engine and runs the inputted query. The Chrome documentation indicates that this is only available if Google has detected a search engine on the site you are trying to search.

This indeed seams to be the case, because writing `stackoverflow.com<Tab>test<Enter>` makes Chrome navigate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=test) while `facebook.com<Tab>test<Enter>` does nothing because the tab-key tabbes out of the address line.

What I'm wondering is then how to indicate to Google that my site has a search engine and how Google needs to format a query in order to redirect a Chrome user correctly to my site when the tab-search feature is utilised. Is it a Meta tag? Is it in robots.txt?

Comment: For anyone who needs the specification of OpenSearch mentioned in @Andreas's answer, [OpenSearch](https://github.com/dewitt/opensearch).
Also here's mozilla's [description file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/OpenSearch).
Other links:
[Official website](http://www.opensearch.org/Home)
[Tutorial](https://perishablepress.com/custom-opensearch-functionality-for-your-website/)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After a little digging I found [this](http://blog.coredumped.org/2012/04/opensearch-how-to-get-google-chrome-to.html) page that describes this. Also you can read in Stackoverflow's source code and find this line of code:

```
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
```

What it does is indicate to Google that the description for how to use your search engine in the file `/opensearch.xml` which contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
  <ShortName>Stack Overflow</ShortName>
  <Description>Search Stack Overflow: Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers</Description>
  <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
  <Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico</Image>
  <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://stackoverflow.com/search?q={searchTerms}"></Url>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

Comment: I can't see either rel="search" _or_ any mention of "opensource" in the source for either the front page of auctions.yahoo.co.jp, _or_ for any page I get back as a search result, so there must be more to this story. Maybe because 7 years have passed between this answer and today.

Comment: @Hakanai
Indeed, there is no trace of ``rel="search"`` in the yahoo (https://www.yahoo.com/) website. Because of that (firefox) can't detect that this website supports site-search. OpenSearch is for browsers to *detect* search engines, not implement them!

Answer (score 4):

When I implemented a search function for my online Klingon dictionary, I found that I didn't need an OpenSearch description for Chrome to autodetect it as a search engine.

*NOTE: While this is a simpler method, it does not allow for advanced features like specifying a search template, a custom favicon (Chrome automatically uses the favicon of the site) etc. It also might not work for other browsers than Chrome.*

I started off with the instructions here [Search Engine Autodiscovery: Google Chrome Autodiscovery](https://martin-thoma.com/search-engine-autodiscovery/#google-chrome-autodiscovery), which say:

> Interestingly the auto discovery only works if the search engine is at the homepage. You have to have either an input field of the type `search` or of the type `text` with the name `s`:
>
> ```
> <form>
>   <input type="search" name="s" />
> </form>
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> <form>
>   <input type="text" name="s" />
> </form>
> ```

I got Chrome to autodetect the search engine on my website [klingonska.org](http://klingonska.org/) without using an OpenSearch description.

However I deviated from the above description, as I found I didn't need have to have field called `s` nor use `type="search"`. My final `<form>` look something like this (in reduced form).

```
<form method=get action="dict/">
  <input name=q placeholder="Search dictionary…">
  <button type=submit>Search</button>
</form>
```

The cruicial factors seemed to be that the form was located on the root page `http://<domain>/` page (*not* a subpage like `http://<domain>/<dir>/<something>.html`). And, IIRC, that the search form contain only a single field.

Comment: It seems to work with a parameter named "q" too (like Google does).

Comment: @LewisKelsey I see no reason that it wouldn't, but haven't tried it. If you can, please try it and then add it to the answer above. :)